# PHP - Deshabilitar botón en caso de que no se cumpla condición

Tags: php, html, formularios, condiciones, botón

¿Cómo podría yo deshabilitar el botón de pagar, es decir, que no haga el onclick a la función, siempre y cuando el if planteado no sea ese? En el input es donde debo introducir el valor(123). Poniendo únicamente 123, debe ejecutarse la acción del botón.

```
<input type='radio'><img class='paypal' src='fotos/paypal.png'/>
<input type='text' name='clave'/>

    <form action="pagado.php" method="post">   
    <p>
    <span>
        <input id='botones' type='submit' value='Pagar' onclick='return comprar()'/>
    </span>
    </p>

    <?php
    $pagar=$_GET['clave'];
    if($pagar!='123'){
        echo "<disabled='true'>";
    }
    ?>
    </form>
```

Comment: Tienes que hacerlo en el lado del cliente con javascript.

Comment: No es muy claro tu planteamiento. ¿El botón debe estar desactivado y activarse **ùnicamente cuando se escribe el valor `123` en el input**? No necesitas PHP para eso, como dice @alanfcm lo puedes hacer desde el cliente.

Comment: Hola. La respuesta a tu pregunta es sí, eso debe hacer. El problema es que no puedo usar javascript para estas actividades! Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tendrías que hacer lo siguiente:

```
<script>
    function comprobar() {
        if (this.value != '123'){
            var Pagar = document.getElementById("botones");
            Pagar.disabled = true;
        }
    }
</script>

<input type='radio'><img class='paypal' src='fotos/paypal.png'/>
<input type='text' name='clave' onkeyup="comprobar()" />

<form action='pagado.php' method='post'>
    <p>
        <span>
            <input id='botones' type='submit' value='Pagar' onclick='return comprar()' />
        </span>
    </p>
</form>
```

Las operaciones de php del If lo podrías hacer antes si quieres, simplemente con tener la variable declarada y asignar el valor... Es suficiente.

Espero que te ayude, un saludo!

Comment: Se ve bien planteado tu comentario Rubén, lo único que ahora me dice: 'Notice: Undefined index: clave', y cuando teclee 123 en el input debería funcionar el botón. Gracias!

Comment: Cambia la línea `$pagar=$_GET['clave'];` por `$pagar=$_GET['clave'] ?? '';`

Comment: ¿Porqué no lo validas con JavaScript? Porque un GET es porque ese elemento viene de otra página o desde tu página pero por parámetro/método GET.. Pero si lo que necesitas es validar que cuando el usuario meta 123, el botón se habilite, eso se hace con JS, igual te puedo pasar un ejemplo si lo necesitas

Comment: Me serviría de gran ayuda Rubén, muchas gracias.

Comment: Aquí tienes, con esto sería suficiente :) 
`<script>
 function comprobar() {
  if (this.value != '123'){
   var Pagar = document.getElementById("botones");
   Pagar.disabled = true;
  }
 }
</script>

<input type='radio'><img class='paypal' src='fotos/paypal.png'/>
<input type='text' name='clave' onkeyup="comprobar()" />

<form action='pagado.php' method='post'>
 <p>
  <span>
   <input id='botones' type='submit' value='Pagar' onclick='return comprar()' />
  </span>
 </p>
</form>`
Un saludo!

Comment: Perfecto :) gracias por orientarme. Lo único que detecto es que cuando presiono una tecla, y la suelto (onkeyup) pulse la tecla que pulse, se desactiva el botón de pagar. El botón ha de estar desactivado a no ser que teclee en el input 123. Solo en ese caso se puede clickear en el botón. El type='radio' lo quitaré ya que no me será necesario. Perdona las molestias.

Comment: Es decir, pongo 123 y el botón sigue desactivándose. Es raro ya que el if me lo has planteado muy bien.